# Color of turtles report

Tags: colors, netlogo

I make agents with a random-float color statement

```
ask turtles [set color random-float 100 ]
```

I get color number such as 213.45 and 23.67. This is fine. My question however is how to count the frequency of a specific category of colors (for example: 213.45: 5 times) and the total number of colors. I need a reporter. I know how to list colors:

```
to-report color-turtles
  report [color] of turtles
end
```

but I don't know how I can count them.

EDIT: . instead of ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when doing science, always use the point as a decimal separator.

Second, you need to say what you mean by a "specific category".  If you truly mean *specific* (in your example, 213.45), then the answer is each category occurs once.  (Or else there is something wrong with random-float.)  So what you really need to do is histogram your data, where you specify the bins.  Unfortunately, NetLogo does not build in this functionality.  See https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/367

Here is how I would do it.  Build a reporter procedure that puts each color in a category and report the category.  (The simples approach would be to round to an integer.) Use the table extension to increment the count by 1 each time you encounter the category.

**Edit:**

If you already know the colors, you could get a count for any color by using

```
to-report countColor [#color]
  report count (turtles with [color = #color])
end
```

For example,

```
to-report color-count
  let _colors remove-duplicates ([color] of turtles)
  let _cts   map [countColor ?] _colors
  report (map list _colors _cts)
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is not helpful. The agents copy the color through different procedures. Some agents will have the same floating number at tick x. I need to know how many agents have color x.
I need the exact color number and the frequency. Rounding is useless here.
So for example a group of 4 agents will have 314.23. I need to know the exact number.

Comment: Well if you are *certain* that they will share *exactly* the same floating point number, then you can still use the same methdod.  A float can be a key in a table.
BUT, as a rule, you should not use floating point numbers for equality comparisons.  See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. They get a number at the start and this number does not change. They copy the number from each other: those with more of something. I need to know who copies what how many times as a form of influence.

Comment: Is that a change in the question?  I.e., do you want to track the copying process, or do you (as originally stated) want a count for each number?  If your question is unchanged, then you can use the table method I listed.  I'll add another approach as well.

Comment: Thank you, this gave an answer to my question. I still need to figure out how I can extract this (e.g. [8.916710216805878 9]) in behaviorspace in a easily edited version but that is another question I suppose